# How to easily copy 502.000 thumbnail images from one hard disk of a VPS to another?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, file-transfer, rsync

For a university-project, I am working on a web-service that crawls certain images and shows them in the interface.

I now hit a little scalability-issue: The 150 GB SSD of the VPS is full. Luckily, I have managed to obtain a 1 TB HDD with the same hosting provider which is mounted using webDAV.

However, I am now facing the problem of moving these 501974 files to their new location. Of course, I'd rather not have the web-interface itself break, so my idea now is:

1. Copy images to new location.
2. Rename current directory, and give a symlink to the new location its old name.
3. Remove the old directory.

However, the actual copying step takes *forever* using `cp`. I've also tried `rsync -zP` but this also takes so long (it ran for multiple hours before hanging) that the shell session breaks beforehand.

Is there another, smarter way to copy/move this large amount of files to its new location on another hard disk?

The VPS is running Ubuntu 16.

Comment: Are both disks on the same pc?

Comment: @LPChip They are both accessible through the command line. I think they are in the same datacenter, but possibly not in the same physical PC. The new 1TB hard disk is mounted using a webDAV-setting in `fstab`.

Comment: Copying 150GB *will* data long. Check your io rate with `iostat`/`dstat` or whatever, and you can calculate an estimate *how* long. The question is why your shell session breaks when copying ... (possibly you need to move a smaller amount of files first, if the disk is running out of space for log files etc.)?

Comment: Actually coping 500k files over WebDAV will take a long time anyways, just because of the overhead. Doesn't your provider have some sort of bulk-import feature, where you can just submit a single tar.gz?